# Python resource.getrusage says no new memory allocated

Tags: python

In the following, I try to measure the current process's memory usage with 
resource.getrusage.

I allocate a large array (and can see the system memory increase with psutil), but getrusage reports that same rss value before and after allocating the array. What's up with that?

```
import psutil
import os
import resource
import numpy as np


def total_memory():
    v = psutil.virtual_memory()
    s = psutil.swap_memory()
    return v.used + s.used

result = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF)
print "resource START ", result.ru_maxrss, result.ru_ixrss, result.ru_idrss, result.ru_isrss
init = total_memory()
print "psutil   START ", init

data = np.random.rand(10000,10000)

result = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF)
print "resource   END ", result.ru_maxrss, result.ru_ixrss, result.ru_idrss, result.ru_isrss
print "psutil     END+", total_memory()-init
```

reports:

```
resource START  1586580 0 0 0
psutil   START  5074391040

resource   END  1586580 0 0 0  # same
psutil     END+ 793374720  # total memory increase by this much
```

Python 2.7.6. Ubuntu 14